# Merge multiple tiff files into one tiff file (not different band)

Tags: merge, tiff, python-xarray, rasterio

I have tried firstly make different xr data throuh for loop then merge and produce tiff. But the output tiff range between -340e^36, 340e^36 and there is not illustration.

```
##rad2mm scaling factor.
scaling_factors = {1: (az_res*PRF) / (dfDCs[0]* 2 * np.pi), 2: (az_res*PRF) / (dfDCs[1]* 2 * np.pi), 3: (az_res*PRF) / (dfDCs[2]* 2 * np.pi)}
print(scaling_factors)

outbovl = bovlpha*0
for subswath in [1, 2, 3]:
    # Create a GeoDataFrame for the current subswath
    g = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        {'bovl': globals()[f'overlap_gdf{subswath}'].index.values},
        geometry=globals()[f'overlap_gdf{subswath}'].geometry,
        crs={"init": "epsg:4326"}
    )

    # Create a GeoCube with the same spatial dimensions as 'aa'
    bovls = make_geocube(vector_data=g, like=aa.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim='lon', y_dim='lat'))
    bovls = bovls.rename({'x': 'lon', 'y': 'lat'})

    # Interpolate the 'bovls' data to match the spatial dimensions of 'bovlpha'
    #bovls = bovls.rio.interp_like(bovlpha)
    bovls = bovls.interp_like(bovlpha)

    # Create a binary mask where 'bovls' is multiplied by 0 and then added by 1
    bovls = bovls * 0 + 1

    # Multiply 'bovlpha' by the binary mask 'bovls' to apply the mask
    bovlphatemp = bovlpha * bovls
    if subswath in scaling_factors:
        bovlphatemp = bovlphatemp * scaling_factors[subswath]

    # add the grid values to the final output
    outbovl = outbovl + bovlphatemp
    # Export 'bovlphatemp' to a GeoTIFF file for the current subswath
    # export_xr2tif(bovlphatemp.bovl, f'subswath{subswath}.tif')

##I need the merge the subswath{sw}.tif, but I didn't manage it.    
export_xr2tif(outbovl.bovl, outtif) #.bovl, f'subswath{subswath}.tif'
```

I have tried also rasterio to merge the tiff file but it produces the merged tiff which only includes the first tiff, noth second and third one.

```
## I put the code, maybe it can help me to find another way.
##merge the subswaths
subswath_files = ["subswath1.tif", "subswath2.tif", "subswath3.tif"]
src_files_to_mosaic = []
print(subswath_files)

for subswath_file in subswath_files:
    src = rasterio.open(subswath_file)
    src_files_to_mosaic.append(src)

print(src_files_to_mosaic)

mosaic, out_trans = merge(src_files_to_mosaic)

#Optionally, set the output file's spatial reference and affine transformation
out_meta = src.meta.copy()
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": mosaic.shape[1],
                 "width": mosaic.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_trans})

#Specify the output file name and path
output_file = "merged_subswaths.tif"

#Create the merged GeoTIFF file
with rasterio.open(output_file, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(mosaic)
```